# Error when installing FLTK 1.3.3 on mac OS X 10.10

Tags: macos, fltk

So I am trying to install FLTK on my mac OS X 10.10. I follow the README.OSX.txt file, but when I get to actually installing it on the *make* command, I get the following error and warning:

```
Fl_cocoa.mm:4080:5: error: unknown type name 'NSOperatingSystemVersion'
    NSOperatingSystemVersion version = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion];
    ^
Fl_cocoa.mm:4080:69: warning: instance method '-operatingSystemVersion' not found (return type defaults to 'id') [-Wobjc-method-access]
    NSOperatingSystemVersion version = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion];
                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSProcessInfo.h:20:12: note: 
      receiver is instance of class declared here
@interface NSProcessInfo : NSObject {
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this error or anything that I could do to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Was you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

First go to the fltk-1.3.3 folder and type `export CXX=c++`. This will tell the compiler to use Clang++ to compile FLTK. Then type `./configure` and `sudo make install`. That's it. After this, you might want to check if FLTK is properly installed by typing `fltk-config --version` and to if it gives `1.3.3`.